# How to traverse a concatenated string in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have a concatenated string like

```
str = 1010,5050,6079
```

I want to separate the string. In JavaScript, I can do

```
string = Srt.split(","):
```

and get the result

```
string[2]=5050
```

Is there a way to do this in VB.NET?

Comment: It's exactly the same in VB.Net! :)

Comment: My question was my answer! rsss. Thks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same in VB.NET

```
Dim input As String = "1010,5050,6079"
Dim result As String() = input.Split(",")

result(0) //contains 1010
result(1) //contains 5050
result(2) //contains 6079
```

Comment: This answer is a bit better than @Jonathan's, because it does not hard-code the size of the array.

Comment: There is no need to harcode the array size as you mentioned. I even don't declare the array when I tend to split. eg: string first = sourceString.split(",")(0)

Answer (score 0):

There is no diference. Try with the same code in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET):

```
Dim shoppingList As String = "Milk,Eggs,Bread"  
Dim shoppingItem(3) As String  
shoppingItem = shoppingList.Split(",")
```